# why i can't display an array of images encoded in base64 and sanitized with angular 7 from an api

Tags: express, angular7

so i have images saved in mondodb in binary buffer , when trying to display them with angular 7 after encoding them in base64 and sanitize them , nothing is showing in the browser tho there is no problem occurring .

i ve been trying to change loop and take off the sanitization but still the same problem

```
 getAllClaims(): void {
    this.restApi.getUser().subscribe(data=>{
      this.Claim = data.posts;

    let  i=0;
     this.Claim.forEach((keyword)=>{

    this.imgService.getImg(keyword.image[0]).subscribe(data=>
      {

          this.bytes=data.img.data.data;
          this.uints =new Uint8Array(this.bytes);
         // var len =this.uints.byteLength;

         this.base64 =btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,this.uints));
          this.url ='data:'+ data.img.contentType+ ';base64, '+ this.base64;
          this.imageurl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.url);
        //  console.log(this.imageurl);


          this.arr[i]=this.imageurl;
         i++;
          console.log(this.arr[0]);
      }
      )    
 });
this.Claim.forEach((keyword)=>{

 this.restApi.getAnalyze(keyword.desc).subscribe(data=>
  {


      this.analyse=data.document_tone.tones;
      this.arra.push(this.analyse);
    console.log(this.arra);
  }
  )  
 })

    });
  };
```

i just need to know where i want wrong , cause i have no error to that can give me a hint

Comment: what does `console.log(this.Claim)` give you?

Comment: [{…}]
0:
createdAt: "2019-07-01T10:32:54.651Z"
desc: "Dejected, Bud returns to his office. Gekko subsequently places an order for Bluestar stock and becomes one of Bud's clients. He gives him some capital to manage, but the other stocks Bud selects lose money—suggesting that he can only pick winning stocks with the use of inside information."
image: ["5d1a08d3796af83ad03ca0c8"]
updatedAt: "2019-07-01T13:21:23.952Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5d19e1569c8d7027e0acb06f"

Comment: perhaps share the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Claim))` here...

Comment: {
    "image": [
        "5d1a08d3796af83ad03ca0c8"
    ],
    "_id": "5d19e1569c8d7027e0acb06f",
    "desc": "Dejected, Bud returns to his office. Gekko subsequently places an order for Bluestar stock and becomes one of Bud's clients. He gives him some capital to manage, but the other stocks Bud selects lose money—suggesting that he can only pick winning stocks with the use of inside information.",
    "createdAt": "2019-07-01T10:32:54.651Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-07-01T13:21:23.952Z",
    "__v": 0
}